# Bash. Line-by-line output into another procedure

Tags: git, bash

I've got a simple script for GIT:
`cp --parents $(git diff --name-only $1 $2) $3`

`git diff ...` - get modified files list between commits ($1 and $2).

`cp --parents ...` - copies them into desired directory ($3).

But the only problem exists: white spaces in directory names. Script doesn't work properly in that case. Obviously each line of `git diff` output should be wrapped into quotes, but how?

Or is there another solution? Cannot find it yet.

Comment: Correctly reading line-oriented content is BashFAQ #001: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git diff` supports a `-z` option that will NUL-separate the names. You can then pipe it through `xargs`. Example:

```
$ git diff -z --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | xargs -I% -0 cp --parents "%" /tmp/
```

Options to `xargs`:

- `-0` causes it to expect input data to be NUL-separated;
- `-I%` makes it run the command once per input, and replace `%` in the command line with the input (apparently `-i%` on Windows?). `%` was arbitrarily chosen because it's short, you can use `-IFOO` / `"FOO"` as well;
- `cp ...` the command to execute.

I used `/tmp/` as a safe example.

So this should effectively run

```
$ cp --parents "file1" /tmp/
```

and so on. Alternatively, you can read the output of `git diff` line-by-line within Bash.

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | ( while read fn ; do cp "${fn}" /tmp/ ; done )
```

Comment: I've got: `xargs.exe: invalid option -- I`. OS is Win2008.

Comment: Replaced with lowercase "i". Seems like working. But it would be nice to have this syntax explained, please.

Comment: I'd consider combining the approaches -- using NUL-delimited output *and* a `while read` loop. (In this case, it needs to be `while IFS= read -r -d '' fn; do ...`); that way you get the best of both world, including unambiguous handling of filenames with evil names (containing literal backslashes, literal newlines, etc).

Comment: The second solution looks like the one I searched, but both are working pretty well. Thank you! Just one note: `do cp --parents "${fn}"` - to make it work the way other solution do.

Comment: ...without adding `-r` and clearing `IFS`, by the way, you'll have other bugs as well -- names with trailing whitespace won't work, names with literal backslashes will have them stripped, etc.

Comment: @MadBrozzeR, the curly brackets are unnecessary; `cp --parents "$fn"` is entirely equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Let's be paranoid here, and do this in a way that works even with highly unusual / potentially malicious filenames:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  cp --parents -- "$fn" /tmp/
done < <(git diff -z --name-only -- "$1" "$2")
```

- Clearing IFS (`IFS= read`) prevents trailing whitespace within names from being stripped.
- Using the `-r` argument to `read` prevents literal backslashes within filenames from being honored, and thus stripped.
- The use of `diff -z` and `read -d ''` NUL-delimits names; NULs are the only character which can't exist inside a POSIX filename.
- The `--` makes `cp` treat filenames as, well, filenames, even if they start with `-` characters and would otherwise be treated as options. Likewise for the usage in `git diff`.
- Using the `< <(...)` construct instead of putting the `while` loop on the right-hand side of a pipeline means you can, if you wish to, set variables inside the loop, and those variables will still exist later.

---

It's come up that some versions of the msys runtime environment (particularly including that shipped with "git bash" for Windows) don't support process substitution. Thus, it may be potentially necessary to use a pipeline (with all the [caveats this implies](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)):

```
git diff -z --name-only -- "$1" "$2" |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    cp --parents -- "$fn" /tmp/
  done
```

Comment: Sounds clever, but didn't work for me. With the given syntax I have: `line 26: syntax error near unexpected token '<'`, `line 26: '  done < <(git diff -z --name-only -- "$1" "$2")'`. With left-hand `git diff` output I have no errors and empty result dir.

Comment: @MadBrozzeR, that's a clear indication that the shell in use isn't bash; process substitution (the syntax in question) has been around at least through the 2.0 series. If you're using `#!/bin/sh` or invoking a script with `sh yourscript`, don't tag questions bash; POSIX sh (which is what that uses) is a different shell/specification. (That's doubly true on Ubuntu, where `/bin/sh` is provided by dash, rather than being bash running in stripped-down compatibility mode).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've meant 'Shell' instead of 'Bash'. And yes, sh.exe have been used by default. Switched to bash by placing `#!bash.exe` (both in one directory) at the first line of the script. Now I have: `/bin/patch: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented`, `/bin/patch: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented`, `/bin/patch: line 28: <(git diff -z --name-only -- "$1" "$2"): ambiguous redirect`

Comment: Looks like you're using a Windows portability environment that isn't full-featured, so `<()` isn't available. The rest of my answer can be used, but you'll need to use a pipeline, and thus will be unable to set variables inside the loop which are accessible outside it (and will have the other caveats listed in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). I'll amend appropriately.

Comment: It's interesting: this solution requires `/` at the end of destination folder, unlike other, "unsafe" solutions. Though it's not a problem, can be handled. I like this answer, but need time to test if it really safer in mentioned situations then the previous one. By the way, one thing is needed to be corrected, I guess: variables `filename` and `$fn` is used to have same name.

Comment: To be fair, `git` might already prevent some of the possible scenarios (filenames ending in whitespace, filenames with literal backslashes, etc). Or maybe it doesn't; would have to test. Windows, similarly, is pickier about what a valid filename can contain than is a pure POSIX system, which is pretty nearly anything-goes.